# Genesys Composer Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ivr, voicexml, genesys

I'm currently in the process of developing a large VoiceXML IVR application using the Genesys GVP 8.1.5 framework. I have successfully built, tested and deployed two smaller apps with no issues. However, testing on the large app is taking a long time as I have to navigate through all the menu's from the start to test functionality further down the call flow.

I'm looking for some unit testing software that can make this process less painful. This would be simple if I was just testing plain old VoiceXML/Javascript but the apps call middleware functions and connect to media servers so a lot of stuff won't be easy to test on something like JVoiceXML.

I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience in this area and can point me in the right direction? I have Googled this extensively and searched the Genesys forums but still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Nu Echo publishes a relatively inexpensive tool based on Eclipse for accomplishing exactly this.  You use the Eclipse plugin to draw scenarios and submit jobs to a robot server based on Asterisk.  You can either host the robot server yourself or have Nu Echo host it for you.  Details: http://nubot.nuecho.com/

Edit: I don't work for Nu Echo, but I've been a very happy user with thousands of automated unit tests under my belt.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this on another forum. I'll link to it in case anyone else has questions related to this:

http://www.sggu.com/smf/index.php/topic,8381.0.html